# How practical is a Scythe?

Tags: weapons, combat

In the story I am creating, I want to have the MC gain a shape-shifting scythe that can change sizes from a keychain to a massive 8-foot scythe. The scythe takes shape into a weapon most ideal for the current user so it also has other weapon forms that can be used for different combat scenarios but the main weapon will be his Scythe. Exactly how practical would a scythe be as the main weapon?

Comment: Well if your enemy is a field of wheat, it's amazing.

Comment: Welcome to the site Foreacle, I put your question on hold for the moment.  As it stands the question doesn't give us enough detail to answer your question.  Whether a weapon is "good" is purely a matter of situation.  There is not really an objective answer to what you have asked.

Comment: I can think of two ways to improve the question, the first is probably the best.  1) Ask for examples in history of the scythe being used in combat.  That is objective and you can base your work on the real world examples.  The other option is to give us a scenario and we can see if a scythe is a reasonable weapon for the scenario...it could be on-topic but would be difficult to get there.  Once you make an edit to the question your question will get reviewed and can be re-opened.

Comment: In the meantime check out the [tour] and [help] to familiarize yourself with the site and how things work.  Again, welcome and happy world building.

Comment: Take a look at actual war-scythes in history, they look more like spears than the farming tool and they were very good against cavalry.

Answer (score 1):

**Main Weapon Aspect**

The scythe is a relatively bad main weapon because its design is for a niche combat situation (you want to cut a large area in short time). And the thing most main weapons have that make them a main weapon are there ability to work in most combat scenarios. Which the scythe is not made for by a any means. A sword is often a "main weapon" because it is very versatile it works in most scenarios but never works as good as a dedicated weapon.

Example:

- **Thrusting** a spear is way better than a sword for this but a sword works as well
- **Parrying** a shield is obvious here but a sword still does its job
- **Farming a large area** a scythe is great here but with a sword you can still do it

**General Weapon Utility**

A Scythe is only relay good for a slash attack not for thrusting and only in rare cases for top down or bottom up attacks. Also you cant really parry with a scythe which also degrades its main weapon utility. But when your main character doesn't experience dizziness after spinning and has a good turning speed he could be a formidable foe. Except maybe for a good archer or other range based fighter.

**Summary**

In most cases it is not a good main weapon so maybe focus on the transformation aspect on the weapon as you can see above a weapon which can turn into the best version for every type of hit can be way better than your common place sword. Or any other medieval weapon.